# Does the [HiddenInput] attribute work, when using @Html.EditorForModel()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, html-helper

I marked the "ProductId" property with "HiddenInput" attribute:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

When i use @Html.EditorForModel() in "Index" view, "ProductId" appeares on the screen.

```
@model SportStore.Domain.Entities.Product

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.EditorForModel()
<input class="AdminButton" type="submit" value="Save changes"/>
}
```

Although, when i use @Html.EditorFor() for each property, "ProductId" is hidden.

```
@model SportStore.Domain.Entities.Product

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductId)
    <nav>Name: <br/>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)<br/></nav>
    <nav>Description: <br/>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)<br/></nav>
    <nav>Price: <br/>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Price)<br/></nav>
    <nav>Category: <br/>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Category)<br/></nav>
    <input class="AdminButton" type="submit" value="Save changes"/>
}
```

So, @Html.EditorForModel() doesn't support [HiddenInput] attribute or i've made a silly :) mistake?

i found the same (but unanswered) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052293/asp-net-hiddeninput-data-attribute-not-working-when-rendered-with-html-editorf?rq=1)

Comment: How does it behave when you use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ProductId)`?

Comment: Actually i don't know whether i need to initialize the ProductId field, i did it for the sake of completeness. Anyway, the "ProductId" doesn't show up.

Comment: I was referring to the idea that you haven't done the same thing in both cases. In the first situation, you've calling `EditorForModel` which calls the `EditorFor` for all children. What you did in your second was call a specific `HiddenFor` which behaves differently. Likely `EditorForModel` is usable, but may require different attributes than you have specified.

Comment: i checked using both: @Html.EditorForModel() and @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductId). ProductId field shows up

Comment: Are you overriding the default model metadata provider (DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider)?

Comment: definitely i didn't do this intentionally) no

Comment: I found the same problem working from the same book. (The [HiddenInput] annotation not working.) However, I couldn't reproduce the way you made it work using the individual `EditorFor`s.